# Availability / validity of variables within classes

Tags: javascript, oop

Normally I am using the sessionStorage-Object to store global variables, but what i fount out is, that variables that are defined outside Javascript Classes, are although available within them. I make an example below. So what i want to know is:

What is the benefit of sessionStorage-Object vs. the usage of such "global" variables that are available everywhere? I do not want to make page reloads because i have a closed application.

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Klassen -->
        <script src="js/classes/Document.js"></script>

        <!-- Main -->
        <script src="js/javascriptklassen.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is javascriptklassen.js

```
var globaleVariable='Ich bin im Parent Context -- ';
var myDoc=new Document();

globaleVariable='Ich bin auch im Parent Context -- ';
var myDoc2=new Document();

globaleVariable='Zusätzlich bin ich auch im Parent Context -- ';
var myDoc3=new Document();
```

This is Document.js

```
var Document = function () {
    this.globaleVariable='Not in parent context';
    this.writeSomethingToHTML();
}

Document.prototype = {
        writeSomethingToHTML: function() {
            var aDiv = document.createElement("div");

            var globaleText = document.createTextNode(globaleVariable);
            aDiv.appendChild(globaleText);

            var localText = document.createTextNode(this.globaleVariable);
            aDiv.appendChild(localText);            

            document.body.appendChild(aDiv);
        }       
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Test in all browsers]

Comment: e.g. "A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: @Roman Granovsky Do i have some benefits when i do not want to make a complete page reload, because i have a closed application?

Comment: You don't want to reload page, but user does :) I don't know what kind of benefits would you like to get from session storage. If you don't know what you need it for then you just don't need it. Use global variables, it's OK.

Comment: @Roman Ganovsky: Ah so it is an additionally protection if the user presses the refresh button i.e. :)